# ml-gradle creating unexpected extra forest in another group node

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

We are using ml-gradle `v4.1.0` and ML `v10.0-3`

We have 2 groups A and B in the cluster. A has 6 nodes and B has 4 nodes.

Despite using the property `mlDatabasesWithForestsOnOneHost` ml-gradle is creating an extra forest in B group (along with one forest in A group for a particular DB).

Since this `mlDatabasesWithForestsOnOneHost` property is set it should never create more than 1 primary forest for a particular DB.

I have also set the property `mlForestsPerHost` with `DB_name,1`

Please help.

Comment: Please open a bug in the ml-gradle github project; include any relevant properties in gradle.properties so it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

I think mlDatabasesWithForestsOnOneHost is unstable and ignores mlDatabaseGroups:  https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/issues/593

Comment: That's fixed now.